# Using the result of a function in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL (Server) query like the following:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyId, CalcAmount1, CalcAmount2) 
SELECT a.Id, a.Value1 - CalcValue, myFunc(a.Value1, a.Value2) AS CalcValue
FROM MyTable2 a
WHERE a.SomeValue = 35
```

So, the question is, can I do something akin to what I am attempting with the result of `MyFunc()` above; that is, can I alias the result and use it in the query?  If not, is there another way to achieve the same thing?  Obviously, I don't want to call the function twice.

Comment: You can put the result of function in a column and use that statement as a subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery or CTE.  SQL Server also lets you do this with a lateral join:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyId, CalcAmount1, CalcAmount2) 
    SELECT a.Id, a.Value1 - v.CalcValue, v.CalcValue
    FROM MyTable2 a OUTER APPLY
         (VALUES (myFunc(a.Value1, a.Value2) )
         ) v(CalcValue)
    WHERE a.SomeValue = 35;
```